# How do I get reasonable server-side NFS log output?

Tags: linux, debian, logging, nfs

I was experiencing some problems with `nfs-kernel-server` on Debian *stretch* which I could solve by luck. Still, I learned that the log output was not of much help of me. I would like to change that to extend my NFS-problem-solving capabilities.

This is my `/etc/exportfs` file:

```
/srv/nfs/magicbox_rootfs 127.0.0.0/8(rw,no_root_squash,async,no_subtree_check,insecure)
```

When that line is commented, i.e. when I don't have access rights on my local machine, following connection attempt does not have any effect on

- `/log/syslog`
- `/log/messages`
- `/log/dmesg`
- `/log/kern.log`
- `/log/debug`
- `/log/daemon.log`

:

```
sudo mount -v -t nfs 127.0.0.1:/srv/nfs/magicbox_rootfs /tmp/mountdir/
```

## My own solving attempts

When I run

```
sudo rpcdebug -m nfsd -s
```

as [this page recommends](https://www.serverstack.com/blog/2012/11/21/debugging-nfs-file-access-on-server-and-client-side/), connection attempts *do* generate a entry in `/log/kern.log`, but it is rather meaningless:

```
Aug 31 11:49:43 manuelthinkpad kernel: [125549.999823] nfsd_dispatch: vers 4 proc 0
```

Can someone suggest how I achieve meaningful NFS log entries? I'm under the impression NFS does not do any logging by itself, but rather relies on third-party deamons and tools to do the logging for it. However, this doesn't make it easier for new users like me.

Comment: I don't know about reasonable, but to prevent multiple GB of verbose NFSD and NFS logs in kern.log and syslog, i disabled logs completely: 

`sudo rpcdebug -m nfsd -c` and `sudo rpcdebug -m nfs -c`